# How do I combine a QImage and QPixmap?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qpainter

I'm using PyQt, and I've loaded an image from disk into a `QPixmap`.  I've also created a mask, using:

```
self.mask = QImage(self.image.width(), self.image.height(), QImage.Format_Mono)
self.mask.fill(0)
```

I'd like to combine the two for display, such that any pixels colored black in the mask are drawn in translucent red over the image when I render it.

I've created a custom widget, that renders the image in the paint event like so:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    p = QPainter(self)
    r = event.rect()

    p.drawPixmap(r, self.image, r)
```

This works fine.  What I'm less clear on is how to take the data in the mask and paint a translucent red only over those pixels in the destination image.

I've tried turning the mask into a clipping region, like this:

```
mask = QPixmap.fromImage(self.mask.createMaskFromColor(self.mask.color(0)))
p.setClipRegion(QRegion(mask))

color = QColor(255, 0, 0, 128)
p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
p.setBrush(QBrush(color))
p.drawRect(r)
```

... but it doesn't draw anything (and draws a translucent red box over the whole image if I don't call `setClipRegion`).

I also tried creating the mask as a `QImage.Format_ARGB4444_Premultiplied`, and using transparency.  And while this does work, and I can edit the mask in my program (and verify that some portions of the mask are transparent and some portions are opaque) the `self.mask.createAlphaMask()` method returns a solid white rectangle.

Do the "create mask" methods actually do anything?

Comment: Can you give a complete example? That mask is full black.

Comment: Yes, that mask is full black.  I have ways of editing it working in the program.  It's combining the `QImage` and `QPixmap` that's causing problems for me.

Comment: what do you really want to do? Is it to highlight some parts of one image? What's really in your mask? Is it black where you whant to highlight the pixel or some other colour?

Comment: I have an image I want to display to the user.  I want the user to be able to draw a mask over the image.  Sometimes I want to display the mask over the image, such that the white areas are transparent and the black areas are opaque.  Sometimes I want to display the mask over the image such that the white areas are transparent and the black areas are translucent red.

Answer (score 2):

Either change your mask's design or create a new QImage based on your mask. Then draw the QImage on the destination. It is not only a method that works, but also a method that is faster than drawing single pixels or sth. similar. I tried several ways and this was the fastest so far (on a QGLWidget).

The idea is that you encode the transparency, and also the non-marked pixels, in the QImage directly, like this:

```
QImage dest(<width>, <height>, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
dest.fill(qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
for (int y = 0; y < <height>; ++y) {
    QRgb *destrow = (QRgb*)dest.scanLine(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < <width>; ++x) {
        if (<should be marked>)
            destrow[x] = qRgba(255, 0, 0, 127);
    }
}
painter.drawImage(0, 0, dest);
```

For reference, take a look at the code here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/gerbil/svn/60/tree/trunk/gerbil-gui/bandview.cpp#l59